# How to set alert when cpu usage reaches 100% Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, cpu-usage, alert

Is there a way to set an alert, email or sms, when a certain windows xp machine's cpu reaches 100%?

Comment: Why do you need this? Chance are there's a better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: Are you looking for a programmatic solution?  If not, this is a question for superuser.com, not stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this, the machine is not Windows XP, but Windows Server 2003. The answer I have found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/24621/how-can-i-send-an-alert-on-cpu-usage-in-windows-server-2008

Comment: You can actually delete your own question.